# Is it possible to shift Amazon S3 Glacier Storage files into Glacier Deep Archive?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have 8TB files in AWS S3 Glacier Storage. I just want to move that into Glacier Deep Drive.

What would be the cost for retrieving the data from Glacier storage to S3, then moving it into the Glacier deep archive or can we have option to move it directly from Glacier storage to Glacier Deep Archive?